# Trying to control an application using its command line interface using python's subprocess module

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

So I use a program DSI Studio and I am doing a lot of repetitive tasks that I would like to automate. It has a command line interface that works for me with the command

```
dsi_studio --action=trk -source=HarveyReg2.hdr.src.gz.odf4.f5rec.012fx.rdi.gqi.0.2.fib.gz --method=0 --
seed=leftprechiasm.nii.gz --roi=1.nii.gz --fiber_count=100 --output=track5.trk
```

it does exactly what I want and outputs a file. 
However when I try

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("dsi_studio --action=trk --source=HarveyReg2.hdr.src.gz.odf4.f5rec.012fx.rdi.gqi.0.2.fib.gz --method=0 --fa_threshold=0.00000 --turning_angle=70 --step_size=0.01 --smoothing=0 --min_length=0.0 --max_length=300.0 --initial_dir=0 --seed_plan=0 --interpolation=0 --thread_count=12 --seed=leftprechiasm.nii.gz --roi=1.nii.gz --fiber_count=100 --output=track4.trk", shell=True)
```

I get back return code 1. The same thing happens if I use subprocess.run. I have dinked around with different permutations to no avail. the only thing I have managed to get a 0 return code from is

```
subprocess.call('cd /d G:\Programs\dsi_studio_64', shell=True)
```

which I attempted because that is the directory I need to be in for the command to work in cmd. but even after doing that it still doesn't work. I'm pretty novice at python and I have spent a few days reading questions like mine but when I try to implement their solutions by template matching I have had no luck.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Try, using subprocess.Popen it doesn't block, allowing you to interact with the process while it's running, or continue with other things in your Python program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each subprocess call makes its own shell, so your `cd` isn't actually affecting your later call, which is then breaking because you're in the wrong directory. Try

```
os.chdir("G:\Programs\dsi_studio_64")
subprocess.call("dsi_studio --action=trk --source=HarveyReg2.hdr.src.gz.odf4.f5rec.012fx.rdi.gqi.0.2.fib.gz --method=0 --fa_threshold=0.00000 --turning_angle=70 --step_size=0.01 --smoothing=0 --min_length=0.0 --max_length=300.0 --initial_dir=0 --seed_plan=0 --interpolation=0 --thread_count=12 --seed=leftprechiasm.nii.gz --roi=1.nii.gz --fiber_count=100 --output=track4.trk", shell=True)
```

you can also do it with the `cwd` argument to call(), like

```
subprocess.call("your long command", cwd="directory")
```

Comment: well I still get returncode 1 but it generates the file and the file is what it should be so I'm not going to sweat it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess.Popen.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess

def run_process(exe):
    'Define a function for running commands and capturing stdout line by line'
    p = subprocess.Popen(exe.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in run_process("G:\Programs\dsi_studio_64\dsi_studio --action=trk --source=HarveyReg2.hdr.src.gz.odf4.f5rec.012fx.rdi.gqi.0.2.fib.gz --method=0 --fa_threshold=0.00000 --turning_angle=70 --step_size=0.01 --smoothing=0 --min_length=0.0 --max_length=300.0 --initial_dir=0 --seed_plan=0 --interpolation=0 --thread_count=12 --seed=leftprechiasm.nii.gz --roi=1.nii.gz --fiber_count=100 --output=track4.trk"):
        print(line)
```